# Disable wp-admin log on lightbox overlay

Tags: admin, login

When you're logged into the WordPress admin, and your session times out, a lightbox overlay pops up requiring you to log back in.

This is causing a problem for me. If we leave a tab open overnight, I'll wake up to thousands of page hits because of the lightbox refreshing wp-admin every few minutes to see if the status has changed.

Question:
Is there a way to disable the WordPress admin login lightbox?

Comment: Can you simply increase the login timeout?

Comment: Funny - I never thought of that. Suppose I could extend it to 6 months or something. Does it make sense to extend the timeout or to (try) and disable the lightbox login?

Comment: I have never tried to disable the lightbox so I can't say for sure but my feeling is that increasing the timeout will be easier and less error prone, assuming there are no security issues involved in doing so.

Comment: @s_ha_dum toss this suggestion into an answer and i'll mark it as done. thanks!